# How to link images relatively in Inkscape?

Tags: images, inkscape

I would like to make relative links to pictures in an Inkscape file. So when I move the project files (images and the Inkscape master), I wouldn't have to relink the images.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Insert linked image
2. Open XML editor and select the image
3. **Change the xlink:href attribute to be relative instead of absolute.** For example, if your image is in the same directory as your svg file, then the value for xlink:href would look something like this: "./MyPic.jpg"

Example diff:

```
<        xlink:href="file:///home/foouser/svg/20150721_210652-0.JPG"
---
>        xlink:href="20150721_210652-0.JPG"
```

After saving, closing, and moving your svg file along with your image file, Inkscape should still display the image in your file. Also note that after re-opening, Inkscape will keep the xlink:href attribute, but also maintain a separate attribute called sodipodi:absref that will store the absolute location of the image. I've found that this doesn't matter -- you can still move your files around and Inkscape will refer to the xlink:href attribute to find your image.

Tested on Inkscape 0.48

Comment: Thank's for the answer. But my image is higher in an other folder (My folder with the svg is side by side with the one with my pictures or some times higher in the folder organisation) So what should  I write in the link: "./folderimage/Mypic.jpg ? or something else like "../folderimage/Mypic.jpg ? What's the protocole or language used in the link?

Comment: "../folderimage/Mypic.jpg" should work. The language used in the link is simple UNIX path syntax where a forward slash represents a directory separator, a dot represents the current directory, and two dots represents the parent directory.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not familiar with the XML editor it might be more convenient to just right-click on the figure --> Image Properties --> URL: "../my_relative_path/my_figure.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

../stuff/file.ext indeed should work.

For a full guide see here: http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/inkscape-embedding-or-linking ;-)